# Unable to access Excel-File using C# Interop (Windows-Service-Project)

Tags: c#, excel, windows-services, interop

I created a Windows-Service, which reads an Excel-File in the Documents-Folder, modifies it and then saves it into a different folder. Everything works fine, except that `Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filepath)`; cannot access the file...

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException(0x800A03EC): Microsoft
>   Excel cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\user\Downloads\Chargenexport.xlsx'. There are several
>   possible reasons:
>
> ```
> • The file name or path does not exist.
> • The file is being used by another program.
> • The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.
> ```

This is the Exception I get. The Filepath is 100% right and the file is not open or used by a different process. I use the same command and file in a different project (WPF-Application) and it works fine...

Does anyone have a suggestion what I could do? Thank you very much!

Comment: Triple check that Excel is not running in the task manager.  It's common for an orphaned Excel task to be running while developing/debugging C# code that interfaces with Excel.

Comment: Maybe your service does not have access to that folder since it's inside the user profile? For example, your service may be running under the `NetworkService` user account...

Comment: You could start by checking in Process Monitor what exactly happens - do you see the file access there? Does it fail? If so, why (what is the error)?

Comment: Thanks, @CherryDT. My Service did not have the rights to access the file. It took me some time to understand that.